# Group BY and take into account changing values

Tags: sql, group-by, view

I have data in a table like this:

| id | name | timestamp | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-02-07 12:00:01 | Area a |
| 2 | John | 2022-02-07 11:44:23 | Area a |
| 3 | John | 2022-02-07 12:55:25 | Area a |
| 4 | John | 2022-02-07 13:00:06 | Area b |
| 5 | John | 2022-02-07 14:05:41 | Area b |
| 6 | John | 2022-02-07 15:05:41 | Area b |
| 7 | sam | 2021-12-27 10:20:35 | Area a |
| 8 | sam | 2021-12-27 11:35:24 | Area a |
| 9 | sam | 2022-02-07 12:00:01 | Area b |
| 10 | sam | 2022-02-07 12:10:38 | Area b |
| 11 | sam | 2022-02-07 12:17:01 | Area b |
| 12 | sam | 2022-02-07 12:29:01 | Area a |

Is it possible to create a view that tells me how long each user staid in an area ?

If i try a query like this, it doesnt work if a user comes back to an old area

```
Select name, location, MIN(timestamp) AS timeOfArrival, MAX(timestamp) AS timeOfDeparture
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY name, location
```

Here it shows Sam staying more than a month at the same location:

```
 name  | location |    timeOfArrival     |   timeOfDeparture
---------------------------------------------------------------
 John  |  Area a  | 2022-02-07 12:00:01  | 2022-02-07 12:55:25  
 John  |  Area b  | 2022-02-07 13:05:41  | 2022-02-07 15:05:41
 sam   |  Area a  | 2021-12-27 10:20:35  | 2022-02-07 12:29:01  
 sam   |  Area b  | 2022-02-07 12:00:01  | 2022-02-07 12:17:01
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, for a single user and an area, timestamps are alternatively associated with either arrival or departure.

Therefore, you can identify an event as a combination of an arrival and subsequent departure, or a single arrival. I computed an event identifier `eid` as a simple function of the row number of the table partitioned by `name` and `location` and sorted by timestamp.

Then added `eid` to the grouping variables and obtained a table with details of events per user and area:

```sql
select  name,
        location,
        min(timestamp) as arrivalTime,
        max(timestamp) as departureTime
    from (
      SELECT *,
             floor((pid - 1)/2) as eid
        from (
          SELECT *,
                 Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY name,location ORDER BY timestamp) as pid
            from MyTable
        ) q1
    ) q2
group by name, location, eid;
```

| name | location | arrivalTime | departureTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Area a | 2022-02-07 11:44:23 | 2022-02-07 12:00:01 |
| John | Area a | 2022-02-07 12:55:25 | 2022-02-07 12:55:25 |
| John | Area b | 2022-02-07 13:00:06 | 2022-02-07 14:05:41 |
| John | Area b | 2022-02-07 15:05:41 | 2022-02-07 15:05:41 |
| sam | Area a | 2021-12-27 10:20:35 | 2021-12-27 11:35:24 |
| sam | Area a | 2022-02-07 12:29:01 | 2022-02-07 12:29:01 |
| sam | Area b | 2022-02-07 12:00:01 | 2022-02-07 12:10:38 |
| sam | Area b | 2022-02-07 12:17:01 | 2022-02-07 12:17:01 |

However, if you're only interested in total stay time you can simplify the query and calculate difference of timestamps only between an even row number and the row immediately preceding (with rows ordered by timestamp and properly partitioned). The following example works on sqlite:

```sql
  select name,
          location,
          sum(stayTimeHours)
    from (
      SELECT *,
             case Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY name,location ORDER BY timestamp) % 2
             when 1               -- odd number, arrival
               then 0             -- only accumulate hours, after departure 
             when 0               -- even number, departure
             then CAST((julianday(timestamp) -
                        julianday(LAG(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY name,location ORDER BY timestamp))) *
                        24
                        AS REAL)
             end
              as stayTimeHours
        from MyTable
    ) q1
   group by name,
            location;
```

| name | location | stayTimeHours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Area a | 0.260555550456047 |
| John | Area b | 1.09305556118488 |
| sam | Area a | 1.2469444423914 |
| sam | Area b | 0.176944445818663 |

Comment: It's slightly more complicated than that, a user can have an arbitrary amount of row at any location. I've edited the table to show you how the data really look like.

Comment: @aim I clarified my answer and added another query which answers directly to your question.